# Pass Pointer Events through empty area of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, drift

*Whilst this question references [Drift](https://www.drift.com/), no prior knowledge of this plugin is required as this is essentially just a CSS issue. In short, it is a chat widget that utilises an auto-inserted `iframe` to provide it's service (and it is an absolute **pain** to apply a custom position to).*

## Background

I have recently installed a chat plugin on my client's site (powered by Drift). After much excruciating pain trying to apply a custom position to the `iframe`, I finally managed to get it to position correctly (or as best as it would allow).

*The reason it is so painful is simply because Drift repositions and resizes it's containing iframe based on numerous, very weird, factors, so these need to be tracked.*

## The Problem

As mentioned, the Drift JS automatically resizes it's containing `iframe` according to it's contents. However, sometimes the contents and the calculated height do not match and we are left with an `iframe` much larger than it needs to be, but due to it's functionality, it must have a higher `z-index` than anything else on the page, thus the `iframe` creates a large 'dead' patch where no `pointer-events` can pass through.

Consider the following:

[image: Drift Issue]

Can anyone suggest a way in which I can keep the pointer events of the elements within the Drift `iframe` (red rectangle), but also allow pointer events to pass through in the areas of the `iframe` that there is no content (yellow area)?

## The Problem (Updated)

Please note the red rectangle in the image represents the `iframe`, **not** a containing `div`. *i.e. Ignore my annotation*

## What I have Tried

I have played around with various values for `pointer-events` but have had no luck. I thought that something along the lines of `pointer-events: visiblefill;` would work but unfortunately this is only compatible with SVGs...

My last resort solution is to override the calculated height of the Drift `iframe` but this is extremely dirty and I cannot be sure that my calculated height will be correct, thus the widget may end up looking terrible.